Is there any way to prevent a non-admin user from executing "launchctl unload" on macOS?
I started using a well-known program for self-control on MacOS called Cold Turkey. This program is very powerful, but it's not enough since I can open a Terminal as a non-admin user and execute the command:
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/launchkeep.name-of-the-program.plist

The question is simple: how can I prevent a non-admin user from doing this? I've searched a lot online, but there seem to be only partial solutions. Can I "move" the .plist file to the LaunchDaemons folder and make some adjustments? I tried doing this, but it doesn't seem to work.
I inquired with Felix, the developer of Cold Turkey, about whether it's possible to prevent a non-administrator user on a Mac from executing this command without requiring administrator privileges:
launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/launchkeep.cold-turkey.plist

Felix responded that it's not feasible to prevent this due to the way macOS is designed and the necessary permissions required for the Safari extension to function properly.
Is there any hope left? I don't want to stop using the software; it's really good. Do you have any ideas?

You can try Gatekeeper to disallow the app. I don’t know if it will work because a user land app that doesn’t require admin privileges will be easy to circumvent. You’ll need to be an admin to set it up, so prepare for that

Ultimately, if you really can't stop yourself, then the best solution may not be in software. Best of luck.

@benwiggy, yes, i know that blockers has their limits, but they help a lot. I just want myself to always be in charge of the tech i use, no matter what.

@Allan, how do i disallow the app using Gatekeeper? What it is going to do? I tried searching on internet before commenting with no luck. And what about that link you sent me? It does seems like another thing.

@Allan, I found out the article you wanted to send me, i think: this one but I most say, i really dont like it, since it is not only super time consuming to do that but it is too complicated. Anyways, I will keep searching from time to time if other users have better ideas.

Are you trying to block yourself or someone else? Is this a family or organisation device?

@GrahamMiln I'm trying to just block Firefox from time to time so I don't waste that much time doom browsing on internet. It is not a family or organization device, just a standard MacOS account i use.

You could move the point of control from the computer and to the router or a network device. Many routers have parental controls that can be used to control/limit Internet access.
A managed DNS service, such as Pi-Hole or OpenDNS, can also be used to limit access to specific web sites.

Yes, I already do this, but Cold Turkey Blocker is useful to block some apps or programs that I have on my Mac that can lead to distractions.
